# Filtering NSArray of NSDictionaries by all occurrence of particular key

Tags: objective-c

I have been trying to get around this but so far without any success.

I know how to solve this using for loop but i want to learn it using NSPredicate

I have the following NSArray of NSDictionaries

```
[ { "content"="content1", "path"="/usr/name/..." },
  { "content"="acontent2", "path"="/usr/name/..." },
  { "content"="content3", "path"="/usr/name/..." },
  { "content"="content14", "path"="/usr/name/..." } ]
```

I want to return an array of all values of the "content" key for all items in the array. ie, the return should be

```
[ "content1", "content2", "content3", "content4" ]
```

How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Just a heads up, there is no filtering thus no need for NSPredicate.

Comment: Your question doesn't actually seem to be about filtering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`valueForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ)

```
NSArray *contentItems = [array valueForKey:@"content"];
```

> Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects.
>   The returned array contains NSNull elements for each object that returns nil.

Comment: This is a valid solution which solved my mystery, although it is not using predicates. I wonder if there is a way to solve it using predicates though :)

Comment: Predicates are for filtering, so that's a different problem because you aren't filtering. Filtering would be the answer from @Greg. You are creating a full list of part of the information. Filtering would be a partial list of all of the information...

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like that:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"content =[cd] %@", @"content1"];
NSArray * array = [YourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

This will filter your array to show all values where content = content1.
But this is for filtering the array but the output you want:

```
[ "content1", "content2", "content3", "content4" ]
```

It looks more like sorting.

Hope I explained you how NSPredictate work.

Comment: This is not going to solve my problem I am afraid as it is returning certain content values (in your example content1) rather than all content values as I want. It is not sorting that I am after, no.